# HADOOP PIG - Get max and min for subsets of records using PIG

Tags: hadoop, max, apache-pig, min

I'm importing a CSV file with some data similar to below

```
----------
ID | VALUE
----------
1  |   1
2  |   1
3  |   1
1  |   2
2  |   2
3  |   2
1  |   3
2  |   3
3  |   3
```

What I want to do is to get the max and min value for each id. Output would be something like

```
--------------
ID | MAX | MIN
--------------
1  |  3  |  1
2  |  3  |  1
3  |  3  |  1
```

I'm able to get the max and min of the value column using code similar to below

```
MAX_MIN_VALUE = LOAD 'SampleData.csv'  AS (id:chararray, value:int);
MAX_MIN_VALUE_GROUP = GROUP MAX_MIN_VALUE ALL;
WITH_MAX_MIN = FOREACH MAX_MIN_VALUE_GROUP 
       GENERATE
           FLATTEN(MAX_MIN_VALUE.(id)), MAX(MAX_MIN_VALUE.value), MIN(MAX_MIN_VALUE.value);
```

What I'm struggling to get my head around is how to filter the data so I can get the max and min value for each id. In SQL I'd do a self join but can't think of an equivalent way in PIG.

Could anyone point me in the right direction as to a good approach to take to solve this in PIG?

Thanks in advance for any ideas, greatly appreciated!
Derm

Answer (score 2):

You need to `GROUP BY id` instead of `GROUP ALL`.